# Having mail receiving client specific mailer content

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, nodemailer, mailer

Can we have different mail bodies/content depending upon mail client(its rich or not) on receiver end, while sending a mail using nodemailer?
If a recipient1 is using a basic mail client they should see a basic version of mailer else , if someone is using rich mail client they should see a enhanced/different version of mailer body/content.

Answer (score 0):

[Message options](https://nodemailer.com/message/#commmon-fields) has two properties `text` and `html`. You can fill both with proper data for different clients.